# reload page on right click, but no context menu

Tags: javascript, web-applications, html

There is a webapp where I want to reload the page on right click and along with that behavior I don't want the context menu to be showed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="nocontext">No context.</div>

window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('nocontext').oncontextmenu = function(){
        history.go(0);
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Note**: I copied what Jared Farrish posted on his jsfiddle and what James mentioned about using history.go(0); I tested above script in Explorer 9, Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this:

```
 function click(e) {
  if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape' && e.which == 3) {
   window.location.reload();
   return false;
  } else {
   if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' && event.button==2)
    window.location.reload();
    return false;
   }
   return true;
  }
 document.onmousedown=click;
 document.oncontextmenu=new Function("window.location.reload();return false;"); // line added
```

Besides reload you may use:

```
 history.go(0);
 window.location.href=window.location.href;
```

Comment: The page is reloading but what about the context menu? I don't want that. One more thing, I have a textarea field on the page and I'm not allowed to write something (but I can do in IE).

Comment: This traps the context menu prior to launching and reloads the page. as far as the textarea. I could not tell you without seeing code or a test page.

Comment: See http://synaptik.co.cc/james I am using Google Chrome and the context menu is still there.

Comment: The following line needs to be added to the bottom of the script. It will also disable the right click in the text area as well. document.oncontextmenu=new Function("window.location.reload();return false;");

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way would probably be to intercept the right-click event in the body tag, like so:

```
<html>
    <body oncontextmenu="window.location.reload(); return false;" onload="alert('loaded');">
        Testing 1 2 3 ...
    </body>
</html>
```

"return false" prevents the default contextmenu from popping up.

Writing your own event handler function will give you more control, though.